# Fuzzy matching in R; return common character string between near-duplicate user identifiers

Tags: r, match, character

I am working with secondary user event data that has been collected over the last few years. The providers changed systems at one point in time and in doing so this has muddled-up the user identifier column. What has happened is that in the new system, a prefix (of undefined length) has been added to the front of each user identifier, meaning that there are two user identifiers for the one user. Here is a mock example below:-

```
UserId<-c("+7450df38c6a2c2b18e06", "+6547e4e1645868458dcd", "+3fde2905308abe637fda", 
  "+0d7c1f693fbde98e5214", "+059a31bfea92fae4d292", "+58de3eee8b7b0afef0bf", 
  "+01cdee6d0425f3184b1b", "+2e35e45b40213031e320", "+89de669da4accdf77c14", 
  "+80327216548b4d95fe05", "+8a47ddaace37c5a5870d", "+5415d85869372f40b6f5", 
  "+5f2a35a157cc7c2d1b09", "+e0c57b9d284cf300b12f", "+dc9412a08dc9e321c4ca", 
  "+2127450df38c6a2c2b18e06", "+2126547e4e1645868458dcd", "+21433fde2905308abe637fda", 
  "+2150d7c1f693fbde98e5214", "+215059a31bfea92fae4d292", "+215458de3eee8b7b0afef0bf", 
  "+215401cdee6d0425f3184b1b", "+2182e35e45b40213031e320", "+21889de669da4accdf77c14", 
  "+218880327216548b4d95fe05", "+21118a47ddaace37c5a5870d", "+2115415d85869372f40b6f5", 
  "+2105f2a35a157cc7c2d1b09", "+2100e0c57b9d284cf300b12f", "+244dc9412a08dc9e321c4ca"
)
UserId
```

Here is near-duplicated user identifiers for 15 unique users (2 for each user in this example). From the 15th id, we can see the new prefix being added in i.e. +212,+2154 etc. In my real world data set, this new prefix can be 3-5 digits long; it's not totally defined for all cases.

What I need is a solution to provide me with a common identifier for the duplicated identifiers, preferably made up of the common properties in each duplicate. For instance: "+7450df38c6a2c2b18e06" & "+2127450df38c6a2c2b18e06" =  "7450df38c6a2c2b18e06".

Is there an efficient solution that would execute this in large user event data set?

Comment: Did you check out the `fuzzyjoin` matching package? You can define the similarity/difference of the strings and it should be pretty easy if you define the necessary distance between the strings, which should always be the same if the last user string remained the same between the two data sets.

Comment: If you are looking for prefixes or suffixes, [base R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/startsWith.html) can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

Set the basic lenght of your Id, in you example 21 characters:

```
basic_length<-21
```

Remove eventuals prefix mantaining only the last 21 characters:

```
to_compare<-substr(UserId,(nchar(UserId)-basic_length)+2,nchar(UserId))
```

Identify duplicates using `duplicated` R function:

```
dup<-duplicated(to_compare)
```

Here the list of basic Id duplicated:

```
substr(UserId[dup],(nchar(UserId)-basic_length)+2,nchar(UserId))
 [1] "2127450df38c6a2c2b18" "2126547e4e1645868458" "21433fde2905308abe63"
 [4] "2150d7c1f693fbde98e5" "215059a31bfea92fae4d" "215458de3eee8b7b0afe"
 [7] "215401cdee6d0425f318" "2182e35e45b40213031e" "21889de669da4accdf77"
[10] "218880327216548b4d95" "21118a47ddaace37c5a5" "2115415d85869372f40b"
[13] "2105f2a35a157cc7c2d1" "2100e0c57b9d284cf300" "244dc9412a08dc9e321c"
```

If the aim of your problem is only to have a unique Id, you can easly use this function:

```
paste("+",substr(UserId,(nchar(UserId)-basic_length)+2,nchar(UserId)),sep="")
 [1] "+7450df38c6a2c2b18e06" "+6547e4e1645868458dcd" "+3fde2905308abe637fda"
 [4] "+0d7c1f693fbde98e5214" "+059a31bfea92fae4d292" "+58de3eee8b7b0afef0bf"
 [7] "+01cdee6d0425f3184b1b" "+2e35e45b40213031e320" "+89de669da4accdf77c14"
[10] "+80327216548b4d95fe05" "+8a47ddaace37c5a5870d" "+5415d85869372f40b6f5"
[13] "+5f2a35a157cc7c2d1b09" "+e0c57b9d284cf300b12f" "+dc9412a08dc9e321c4ca"
[16] "+7450df38c6a2c2b18e06" "+6547e4e1645868458dcd" "+3fde2905308abe637fda"
[19] "+0d7c1f693fbde98e5214" "+059a31bfea92fae4d292" "+58de3eee8b7b0afef0bf"
[22] "+01cdee6d0425f3184b1b" "+2e35e45b40213031e320" "+89de669da4accdf77c14"
[25] "+80327216548b4d95fe05" "+8a47ddaace37c5a5870d" "+5415d85869372f40b6f5"
[28] "+5f2a35a157cc7c2d1b09" "+e0c57b9d284cf300b12f" "+dc9412a08dc9e321c4ca"
```

As you can see, position [1] and [16] have the same value:

```
out[1]==out[16]
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This worked really well, gave me a common ID; exactly what I was looking for, thanks!